# Excel VBA add TimeValue 0:00 is not next day

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to add a timeline range at column D in 5 mins intervals by referring the input from the time at column A and the duration at column B, but when the time is at 0:00, it will not show correctly as next day:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d-Mmm-yy h:mm;@"

    Dim StartTime As Range
    Set StartTime = Range("A2:A10")

    firstTime = Range("A2").Value
    lastTime = Range("A2").Value
    endTime = Range("A2").Value
    numTask = 0
    For Each cell In StartTime
        If IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            If cell.Value < firstTime Then firstTime = cell.Value
            If cell.Value > lastTime Then lastTime = cell.Value
            If cell.Value + cell.Offset(0, 1).Value > endTime Then endTime = cell.Value + cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            numTask = numTask + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    Range("D1").Select
    currentTime = firstTime
    ActiveCell.Value = currentTime

    While ActiveCell.Value <> endTime
        currentTime = currentTime + TimeValue("00:05:00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = currentTime
    Wend

End Sub
```

[Cell D7 value is not 2-Apr-16 0:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE7SY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using:

```
currentTime = currentTime + Time(0,5,0)
```

The reason for this is explained in [Microsoft's definition of the `TIMEVALUE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in Excel in the "Remarks" section of the page:

> Date information in time_text is ignored.

For the `TIME` function, date is considered and therefore incrementing the time into the next date will be registered properly.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had tried that but still the same, even tried DateAdd.